# How can we sync WatchKit Timer component with a circular ring anmated image sequence?

Tags: ios, timer, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to build a Watch Timer app which shows Timer component counting upwards. And this timer component is surrounded by an image view which is animated using a sequence of 60 images that change with each second counting.

But there is a delay being observed with timer counting to 1 second and then imageView animation is not in sync with exact moment.

I start my Timer and animation using following button code:

```
@IBAction func clickStartButton() {
    self.secondsRing.setBackgroundImageNamed("yellow-outer")
    self.watchTimer.setDate(NSDate())

    self.secondsRing.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(
        NSRange(location: 0, length: 60),
        duration: 60,
        repeatCount: 0)
    self.watchTimer.start()
}
```

I have yellow-outer0, yellow-outer1 .... etc. This is collection of 60 images.

Comment: Are your animation images stored in the WatchKit app bundle? Some code might help here.

Comment: yes all images stored in watchkit app xcassets and @bgilham I have now added my code to the question.